# Is it possible to generate a client jar that also includes classes from dependency jars if they are being used in any of the Interfaces?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I am using maven-ejb-plugin with generateClient property set to true, I tried maven-assembly-plugIn but that includes all the libraries that are being used. I only want the classes that are being used from dependency jars in the Interfaces to be included in the client jar.

Is there any setting/configuration in Maven appc (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#WLPRG614) that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if what you try to do is a good way but maybe you can use the maven dependency plugin to extract the required classe from your dependent jars.

```
<build>
    <plugins>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                        <includes>yourClass.class</includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```